# TypeError: (intermediate value)[type] is not a function error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to use line chart in my ionic app, but what I get is just blank screen.

Also I am getting an error:

```
 TypeError: (intermediate value)[type] is not a function
 at createChart (angular-chart.js:197)
 at Object.fn (angular-chart.js:150)
 at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:28995)
 at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:29263)
 at done (ionic.bundle.js:23676)
 at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:23848)
 at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:23789)
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'chart.js'])
```

controller.js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers',[])
.controller('AspDashController', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
$scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
$scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
$scope.data = [
  [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
];
$scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
  console.log(points, evt);
};
}])
```

html:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="item item-divider">
        A line chart
    </div>
    <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="series" chart-click="onClick"></canvas> 
</div>
```

index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/angular-chart.css">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably, you had used newest version of Chart, that not supported in ng-charts yet.  Try to use previous version of Chart.js Find it here -> 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.1.1/Chart.js

Comment: I'm getting this when I use the 2.0 branch and angular 1.5 components